# Tooltip for dropdown list items in work item definition in TFS

Tags: tfs

I am customizing work item in TFS. One of the fields is a drop down field with few list items.

```
<FIELD name="Test" refname="Name.Test"
    type="String" reportable="dimension">
    <HELPTEXT>Cost Center to be billed for this task</HELPTEXT>    
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">    
       <LISTITEM value="001">    
       <LISTITEM value="002">    
       <LISTITEM value="003">    
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>    
      <REQUIRED />   
</FIELD>
```

I want to give tool tip for each of the list item. For example, by default for list item 001, the tooltip shows are 001, I want to customize it, like "This is the item 001" etc.  I tried setting help text for each list item, but it gave a validation error. Is it not possible to do this on TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to do.

You could put a link to a wiki page that explains the list next to it.

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip is limited to 255 chars.
For a short list you can do :

```
<HELPTEXT>Cost Center to be billed for this task&#10;This is the item 001&#10;This is the item 002&#10;This is the item 003&#10;</HELPTEXT>
```